# Python3 + selenium + PhantomJS UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

- ENV

  PhantomJS2.1.1;Windows10;selenium-3.8.0;python3
- CODE

  ```
  browser = webdriver.PhantomJS() //throw a UnicodeDecodeError
  ```
- Problem

  > UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position
  >   2: invalid start byte
- Details

  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >         File "d:/devtools/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/IndustryLeaderSpider.py",
  >   line 20, in 
  >           browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('D:/phantomjs.exe')
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py",
  >   line 58, in **init**
  >           desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
  >   line 154, in **init**
  >           self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
  >   line 243, in start_session
  >           response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
  >   line 309, in execute
  >           response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py",
  >   line 460, in execute
  >           return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py",
  >   line 522, in _request
  >           resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
  >           response = self._open(req, data)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
  >           '_open', req)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
  >           result = func(*args)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 806, in 
  >           meth(r, proxy, type))
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 814, in proxy_open
  >           if req.host and proxy_bypass(req.host):
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 2739, in proxy_bypass
  >           return proxy_bypass_registry(host)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 2706, in proxy_bypass_registry
  >           fqdn = socket.getfqdn(rawHost)
  >         File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
  >           hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
  >       UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 2: invalid start byte

---

Do someone have this problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main error seems to be :

```
File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 460, in execute return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data) File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 522, in _request resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout) File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open response = self._open(req, data)
```

Try the following steps :

- Run **`CCleaner`** tool to wipe off all the OS chores.
- Take a **`System Reboot`**.
- While you initiate **`PhantomJS()`** provide the absolute path of the **`phantomjs`** binary as follows :

  ```
  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\phantomjs.exe')
  ```
- Ensure that there is no unnecessary `imports` in your script. Example : **`urllib.request`**
- Execute your `Test`.

Comment: Hi,thanks. Today,my program runs ok!  I just close my vpn client(Lantern) and does not do any changes. As you said, it is also an environmental issue